# String ID for RenderedImage?

Tags: java, string, image

I have to use RenderedImages as parts of keys in a cache (the rest of the key is made up of an  X and Y coordinate pair).

Previously, I wrapped the RenderedImage in a custom class with a string field filename and just used the class's filename/toString() to construct a key, but it turns out the keys absolutely must use RenderedImages.

Now, I'm writing the image to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then using that to make a base64 string using DatatypeConverter, but the resulting string from that is massive and really slows down the program.

Is there a good method of creating some kind of string ID from a RenderedImage that doesn't slow everything down too much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the contents of the image and create an SHA digest or MD5 checksum of the byte contents ? That's going to be fairly unique... 
See https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/how-to-generate-sha-or-md5-file-checksum-hash-in-java/
If scanning the whole file is taking too long, just take the first n characters ?